# Paul Irish 'duck punching' pattern observation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Had a question about the 'duck punching' pattern I first encountered on Paul Irish's blog.  I get the general premise... save a ref to an existing  function, then replace the existing function with a conditional branch that will call a new function if condition is met, or the old version if not.  My question is why do we have to use the "apply" with 'this' as the first param when we call the _old function?  I understand how apply works, but I'm looking for some clarification on why it is necessary.

```
(function($){

        // store original reference to the method
        var _old = $.fn.method;

        $.fn.method = function(arg1,arg2){

            if ( ... condition ... ) {
               return  .... 
            } else {           // do the default
               return _old.apply(this,arguments);
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this example

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: function () {
        return this.foo;
    }
};
o = obj.baz;
obj.baz(); // "bar"
o(); // undefined
```

if you call a method with obj.baz, the object that is behind the dot is the function's context (**this** will refer to this object).
if you store a method in a variable, you lose the information about the context. In that case, the context will be set to the global object.

```
var obj = {
    baz: function () {
        return this;
    }
};
o = obj.baz;
obj.baz() === obj; // true
o() === obj; // false
o() === window; // true
```

A proper context will likely be important for the .method to work as intended.

Comment: I understand that, I guess i don't understand what the 'apply' with this as the first parameter helps prevent.  If we did something similar to what you illustrated above with the duck punching code, 'this' , it is possible that 'this' would be window, so what does the apply help?

Comment: hmmm - not trying to be obtuse and maybe I just need to research some more, but the apply in the duck punching code blindly takes whatever 'this' is currently set to.  I don't see how that's different than just calling _old directly.  Maybe that's what I'm missing.  If I did a direct call to _old, wouldn't 'this' ALWAYS be the same 'this' that the code passes to 'apply'.  So, whats the point of using apply

Comment: Let say the original $.fn.method internally uses other jQuery methods that depend on the this context. Calling it with global context would make the other methods unusable. Also many jQuery functions return this so the chaining is possible. If you return the wrong context also the chaining will be broken.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous comment, cause I found my explanation difficult to understand. The above should be better.

Comment: true - but my point is apply with 'this' as the first param does not change or modify context in any way, it uses the 'this' that is already set, for better or worse

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. If you call _old() directly, the context is set to global object. So using .apply(this) calls the _old with the same context your custom $.fn.method was called. And the answer to "why you should call it with this" is my comment above.

Comment: ah - that was my confusion, calling _old directly, even within the newly defined function, will have window as it's context. I was missing that, and assuming _old would have the 'this' from the caller.  That's what I needed to understand, and why I was asking the question, because I could tell I was missing something important.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `this` because `apply()` needs the first argument to be what `this` should be when calling the old function.

`apply()` is being used so you can easily hand `arguments` which will be treated as the arguments to the old function.

So, when deciding what to pass as `this`, you have chosen to pass on what `this` is in that context.

Comment: The question was why use apply in the first place, not why you then have to pass in `this` as the first argument, I think.

Comment: so its nothing to do with context or what 'this' is set to, just a easy mechanism to pass the arguments to _old?

Comment: Well, when using `apply()`, you have to decide what `this` will be set to.

Comment: @Martijn ...and I didn't answer that?

Comment: @alex not until you edited your answer; the version I read didn't ;-)

Comment: @Martijn I think it did, though I admit I didn't word it very well which probably led to your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to call the original function without `apply`, you let JavaScript decide what to bind `this` to, and that may well be something different from what it would be bound to if you hadn't monkeypatched/duckpunched the original code.

Using `apply`, you ensure that the correct value is used for `this`, e.g. the one the wrapper function is being called with.

Comment: but if i did something like f = jquery.fn._old , and then called f(), 'this' would be window when we called apply. The apply, and maybe im just not understanding, is not preventing anything, but blindly using whatever 'this' is set to.  So what is the point.  I'm beginning to think Alex may be right, just a mechanism to pass the arguments array.

Comment: When duckpunching, you want to recreate the original context for _old as closely as possible. That includes ensuring `this` is set to the same object as if _old was called directly. The generic way to do this is by passing on `this` by using `.apply()`.